# Rewrite numeric ID parameter for hierarchical custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've been banging my head against a wall on this one for a while but I'm not quite sure from all the tutorials I read how to see why this isn't doing what I expect.

I have a page called `shop-guide/shop-page?id=412` (for example)

and I want to change it so it it's `shop-guide/shop-page/id/412/`

As far as I can tell I have my code set up correctly, but when I try to navigate to the page I get a 404, and if I use the $_GET version it doesn't rewrite.

Here's my code: (in `functions.php`)

```
function wptuts_add_rewrite_rules() {  
add_rewrite_rule(  
    'shop-guide/shop-page/id/([^/]*)/',  
    'index.php?p=143&id=$matches[1]',  
    'top' 
);  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'wptuts_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues -

your rewrite rule isn't formatted correctly, this:

```
'shop-guide/shop-page/id/([^/]*)/'
```

should be:

```
'shop-guide/shop-page/id/([^/]*)/?$'
```

and if `shop-guide` and `shop-page` are parent / child pages, this:

```
'index.php?p=143&id=$matches[1]'
```

should be:

```
'index.php?pagename=shop-guide/shop-page&id=$matches[1]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you first need to register your custom querystring variable. You could use `add_rewrite_tag` for this purpose: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

See the **important** note down at the bottom of the codex article

Edit:

You could also use `query_vars` hook to add your own custom query variables.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the additional call (and in rewrite analyzer plugin it's working correctly), but the page is still returning a 404 instead of the actual page.

`function wptuts_add_rewrite_rules() {  
 add_rewrite_tag('%id%','([^&]+)');
 
 add_rewrite_rule(  
  'shop-guide/shop-page/id/([^/]*)/',  
  'index.php?p=143&id=$matches[1]',  
  'top' 
 );  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'wptuts_add_rewrite_rules' );  `